# How to configure correctly CUnit on Eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, cunit

I'm trying to set my CUnit on Eclipse but I got two errors:

- If I lunch without `-lcunit` parameter I have:

> undefined reference to CU_assertImplementation

- If I lunch with `-lcunit` I have:

> bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible lib/libcunit.a when searching for
>   -lcunit

Where am I wrong? There is a good tutorial on how to install?

Windows is the O.S.

Comment: I successfully compiled the example of cunit [there](http://cunit.sourceforge.net/example.html). I installed the packages Cunit and cunit-dev. I created a c project using the example and I added `cunit` in project properties/C C++ Build/Settings/GCC linker/Libraries/libraries(-l). The linker command becomes `gcc  -o "unittest"  ./src/unittest.o   -lcunit` and everything worked fine. My guess is that you are working on windows and eclipse tried to link a windows executable to a library intended for MinGW or something similar.

Comment: @francis yes I'm on windows